# XIB Can't be loaded from within the main bundle. .... why?

Tags: swift, xcode, bundle

**Scenario:** I'm trying to work with 'dynamic views' where a storyboard's subview references a XIB.

But I'm having a problem of loading a particular xib file located within the main (current) bundle.  I would think this would be strait forward.

The following is my simple code:

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class AccountInformationView: UIView, Nib {
    let nibName = "AccountInformationView"
    var contentView: UIView?

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit() {
        guard let view = loadViewFromNib() else { return }
        view.frame = bounds
        addSubview(view)
        contentView = view
    }

    func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView? {
       // let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
        let mainBundle = Bundle.main
        let nib = UINib(nibName: nibName, bundle: mainBundle)
        // check the following line due to crash:
        _ = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as? AccountInformationView
        return nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as? UIView
    }
}
```

It crashes at the line:

```
nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as? AccountInformationView
```

> ...reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle
>    (loaded)' with name
>   'AccountInformationView''

Here's the project layout:

[image]

**Why can't I locate the XIB?**

Answer (score 0):

I see that there is a *xib* in your *project* called AccountInformationView.  But that doesn't mean there's a corresponding *nib* in your *bundle*.

- First of all, the *xib* might not be in the app target, so the corresponding *nib* never gets into the built app bundle.
- Second, you have not given enough information, but I'm guessing this code might be running *in the storyboard* (because this is an IBDesignable view) — and *that* is never going to work, because there is *no* bundle at that time, and even if there were, the *xib* has not been turned in to a *nib*. Only *building* can make a *nib*.

Comment: I'm using the Main.storyboard; and I want to load a xib into a UIViewController (schema) of this storyboard.  So you're correct in #2.   

Please expand on the 'building'.   I'm building the entire application, which contains the xib as well as the storyboard.   .... I'm confuse here.  Soon?

Comment: There is no "solution". You can't do that. That's what I just said. Sure, you can load the nib _in code_ when the app actually runs. But you can't do it as part of displaying the storyboard using IBDesignable.

Comment: Oh.   I'm following a 'dynamic view'  tutorial of using XIB to populate a UIView (assuming within a Storyboard).   That's my goal.  I'll check #1 or your response.

Comment: Per #1: 'xib' might not be in the app target -> I've add my targets image to the original inquiry.   --- How would I check if the xib is IN the app target?

Comment: *** I solve it **.   I had to add the 'copy .xib' in the build phase.

Comment: Yes, that was my first bullet point: "Copy files" is the same as being a member of the app target.